# How to read .xlsx file with apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

See the picture below, I am trying to write a program that can "scan" a given row with no limit of from which cell to which cell, then, find all the "strings" that are identical the same. Is it possible to do that? Thank you.

To give an example so that this will not be very confusing, for ex.: On row H, you see there are customer's names, there are "Coresystem", "Huawei", "VIVO", etc... Now the problem is, what if the names are not grouped together, they are all split up, like, On H5, it will be "Huawei" and On H9, it will be "VIVO", etc, it's like, unlike the picture provided below, on row H all the names are split up, and I want apache POI to find all the customers that have the same name, for ex.: If user enter "coReSysteM", it should be able to find all the `.equalsIgnoreCase` of all Coresystem on row H (btw, the user should be able to enter the customer's name that they want to enter and the row they want to search for), and display from A5, B5, C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, H5 to A14, B14, C14, D14, E14, F14, G14, H5, is it possible?
[image]
I was thinking about setting a formula to find all the customer, for example: =CountIf

These are the code that I am currently trying to do, but then I am stuck with it:

```
package excel_reader;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader2d {
    ExcelReader link = new ExcelReader();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // instance data
    private static int numberGrid[][] = null;
    private static String stringGrid[][] = null;

    // constructor
    public ExcelReader2d(String desLink) {

    }

    // methods
    public void ExeScan() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Sonic\\Desktop\\20191223 IMPORTS.xlsx"));

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        final int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum()), rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

        System.out.print("Enter the rows that you want to search for: (for ex. the rows that stores customer's name) ");
        int searchRows = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the customer's name that you are looking for: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        //int rowNum;

        // Search given row
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(searchRows);
        try {
            for (int j = 4; j < rowEnd; j++) {
                Row r = sheet.getRow(j);
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                }

                // skip to next iterate if that specific cell is empty
                if (r == null)
                    continue;

            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
        }



    }

}
```

ps. I know that this will be very confusing, but please feel free to ask for any kind of questions to help you get rid of the confusion and help me either because this has been a problem for me. Thank you very much and I will super appreciated for your help. Currently using apache poi, vscode, java.

Comment: first think of: what is a **row**?

Comment: What have you tried? I would iterate over the rows in the sheet and get the string content of cell 7 (`H`) from each row. If that string fulfills the requirement, that row is one of the needed rows, else not. One could collect the needed rows in a `List<Row>`. Btw.: `H` is not a row but a column.

Comment: @rioV8 row is like every single line, it's like on excel, row A will be the entire line of the very first line.

Comment: @FlashSonic526 : A or H is **not** a row

Comment: @AxelRichter I wonder what do you mean by `List<Row>`? Please do help me, thanks.

Comment: A `List<Row>` is a [java.util.List<E>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) where the type of elements in this list (`E`) is [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html). Please read https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html, especially https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator and https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents. Then try what I have told in my first comment. Nobody will do all the work for you.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for your information, although still not understanding what a List<Row> is but I will try, thanks and appreciated.

Comment: After I read your now provided code you really first should trying to understand what a row is in a `Excel` sheet. Rows are horizontal. So `4`, `5`, ..., `41` are rows. Columns are vertical. So `A`, `B`, ..., `H` are columns. The column `H` contains the eighth cell `row.getCell(7)` of each row. How to iterate over rows I have linked already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would iterate over the rows in the sheet and get the string content of cell 7 (`H`) from each row. If that string fulfills the requirement `equalsIgnoreCase` the searched value, that row is one of the result rows, else not.

One could collect the result rows in a `List<Row>`. Then this `List` contains the result rows after that.

Example:

`ExcelWorkbook.xlsx`:

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.util.List; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 

import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class ExcelReadRowsByColumnValue {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "./ExcelWorkbook.xlsx";

  String toSearch = "coresystem";
  int searchColumn = 7; // column H
  List<Row> results = new ArrayList<Row>();

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) { // iterate over all rows in the sheet
   Cell cellInSearchColumn = row.getCell(searchColumn); // get the cell in seach column (H)
   if (cellInSearchColumn != null) { // if that cell is present
    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cellInSearchColumn, formulaEvaluator); // get string cell value
    if (toSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(cellValue)) { // if cell value equals the searched value
     results.add(row); // add that row to the results
    }
   }
  }

  // print the results
  System.out.println("Found results:");
  for (Row row : results) {
   int rowNumber = row.getRowNum()+1;
   System.out.print("Row " + rowNumber + ":\t");
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
    System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works! It helps my project has great progress, and thank you. But may I ask on line 39, you used a for each loop, and the conditional statement is  `Row row : sheet`, may I ask what's the second small letter `row` means? I guess that it is the name of an array list but there is no array list named `row`. I really do not know what does it mean, please do help me, thanks. I also wonder why `<Row>` is used after the ArrayList on line 30? Thanks.

Comment: @FlashSonic526: [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work). So `for (Row row : sheet)` means for each `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row` named `row` in `sheet`. And `List<Row> results = new ArrayList<Row>();` means the `results` shall be a `jave.util.ArrayList` which lists `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row`s.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did google and it makes me somewhat confusing, thank you for helping :) Still trying to understanding the code since I am really new to apache poi, thank you very much :)